# What's happen? Suddenly No Sound + Youtube's Videos are played Too Fast in 13.04

Tags: sound, youtube

What has happened? Suddenly the PC have no sound and YouTube's videos are played too fast.
Is there a Flash problem?

Ubuntu Version : 13.04 [Desktop]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `pulseaudio -k` then `pulseaudio -d` should restart pulseaudio and temporarily fix your issue. For a more complete fix that doesn't stop working, I had to download the latest flash and install manually. This should work for you on firefox - other browsers may need the libflashplayer.so placed elsewhere. Google should help if that is the case.

(directions taken from [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4724232))

> Open http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
>
> Choose Linux 32-bit on Step 1
>
> Choose Flash Player 11.2 (tar.gz) on Step 2, download the file
>
> Once download is complete, right click on the file (tar.gz) and click on Extract here
>
> Launch Terminal (Keyboard Shortcut : Ctrl+Alt+T)
>
> Go to that location where you extracted the file
>
> Run this command : sudo mv libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
>
> Launch Mozilla Firefox and check do you have Adobe Flash Player

Comment: Is there a way to just download the flash plug-in as a ordinary file - like a .zip or rpm? I ask because clicking on the download button on the Adobe page causes the Ubuntu Software Centre to launch, which says 'Not Found'. What a pain!

Comment: The left side of the page provides spin boxes for selecting your operating system. You can select a tar.gz file or an RPM from there (the apt file is the one that probably opens the software center)

Comment: yes I did all that and then clicked 'Download' and... see my above comment. Have you actually tried this yourself and found it to work?

Comment: Not since my original post - Just tried on my windows PC and it downloads the tar.gz file. It may be how your browser or xdg open is set to handle things - it shouldn't try to open a tar file using software center however. For any more checking, I would have to wait until I get home.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, yesterday I connected my laptop to the TV and I had to select HDMI Audio output in the Sound Settings menu for having the sound working on TV. This morning I had the HDMI disconnected and the only thing that I had to do for fixing the issue is double clicking in the default audio interface.

[image: Audio setting screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my issue. What a ridiculous problem it is which would be fixed with a single double click

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar issue just by going into the sound settings & picking the correct audio output device (something like 'inbuilt analog audio' iirc).

I think the problem started when a user fiddled with the volume controls & ended up at the sound menu, then inadvertently clicked on a device option. You can go to sound icon hit mixer and fix from there.