# Firefox plays videos without sound

Tags: sound, firefox

After I installed Amarok (which I have uninstalled since then), Firefox doesn't produce sounds when I try to stream some websites, for instance these ones:

http://www.npo.nl/nos-studio-sport-eredivisie/09-04-2016/POW_03079959

http://www.dumpert.nl/mediabase/6750553/2f16a7a8/spartafan_heeft_een_favoriete_speler.html

But youtube does work on Firefox, and Chrome works perfectly fine with all websites.

I've tried to Google it and there are many suggestions on how to solve this problem (such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312529/whats-happen-suddenly-no-sound-youtubes-videos-are-played-too-fast-in-13-04)) but they don't solve my issue. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

I've re-installed Firefox and followed all the tips (here)[https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues#w_plugins] but still no luck. I'm getting desperate.

My PCM sounds is also on:[image]

Comment: how did you reinstall the firefox? Did you purge it completely? to install mozilla from *scratch* you have to delete it first `sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox` then remove `.mozilla` folder that is located in your Home Folder just press *Ctrl+H* to see it. Then `sudo apt-get install firefox` after you can sync it again with your account.

Comment: it is also possible to give it a try to reset your firefox *profile* navigate to *help* --> *troubleshooting info* and choose *refresh firefox*

Comment: @JoKeR I've followed your suggestions (thanks!) but unfortunately it doesn't work. Btw I also uninstalled Amarok following your instructions but still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer on this [site](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2993902/browsers/how-to-get-the-latest-version-of-flash-on-firefox-for-linux-after-adobes-abandonment.html) and will post it here in case it will be helpful for someone else (don't ask me why it works though ;)). Run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

Note that I had already installed `freshplayerplugin`, so I guess the trick was the command line `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`.